# How to know if JS code is executing in browser or in design mode

Tags: javascript, intellisense

I believe intellisense can solve a lot of time and bugs. Lets say I make an ajax call and I know I will get an array of cars.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",            
        url: "GetCars.aspx",
        success: function (cars) {                

            for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++)
            {
                var car = cars[i];
                if(document.designMode)
                {
                   car = { type: "", model: 0, colors: new Array() };
                }
                // Intelissense wors great in here!

                // car.   "the moment I type the '.' I see type, model, and colors

            }
        }            
    });
```

I need something that will return true in visual studio editor and false in the browser. `if(document.designMode)` returns true in VS and in the browser so the line `car = { type: "", model: 0, colors: new Array() };` is always executed. **I don't want the line `car = { type: "", model: 0, colors: new Array() };` to be executed on the browser only on VS so I get intellisense**. How can I do that?

---

### Solution

Thanks to @Shoms I came up with:

```
    var car = null;        

    if (window.navigator.userAgent.length === 212) {         
        car = { type: "", model: 0, colors: new Array() };
    }

    // Intellizense works great :)
```

Note your VS might require a different number. For me I have to try > 500 then <250 ,  < 125  etc until I found that it is length 212.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the userAgent and decide what to do based on it.
You can even set a custom userAgent in some browsers in case you need that too.

```
window.navigator.userAgent
```

So, for example, your condition could be:

```
if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') !== -1) {
   // browser here
} else {
   // VS here (or a non-Mozilla browser, but that's not relevant for development)
   car = { type: "", model: 0, colors: new Array() };
}
```

Comment: `window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla')` returns value greater than 0 in VS editor :/

Comment: That was just an example, I don't use VS, but you can check what it returns that's specific to it... or go for `index.Of('Chrome')` if you use Chrome, etc... I just gave you the approach, not the exact code you have to use.

Comment: `window.navigator.userAgent.length === 212`  Returns true only on VS. So I will use that thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure you don't leave that in your production code. :)